# Extract month level precision from a date time column and make all day to 1 in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a time series, month level data as shown below.
df:

```
                   date
0   1997-01-01 00:00:00
1   1997-02-02 00:00:00
2   1997-03-03 00:00:00
3   1997-04-02 00:00:00
4   1997-05-02 00:00:00
5   1997-06-01 00:00:00
6   1997-07-01 00:00:00
7   1997-08-31 00:00:00
8   1997-09-30 00:00:00
9   1997-10-31 00:00:00
10  1997-11-30 00:00:00
11  1997-12-31 00:00:00
12  1998-01-01 00:00:00
13  1998-02-28 00:00:00
14  1998-03-31 00:00:00
```

from the above data I would like to extract month level precision and make all the day to `01`

Expected output:

```
          date
0   1997-01-01
1   1997-02-01
2   1997-03-01
3   1997-04-01
4   1997-05-01
5   1997-06-01
6   1997-07-01
7   1997-08-01
8   1997-09-01
9   1997-10-01
10  1997-11-01
11  1997-12-01
12  1998-01-01
13  1998-02-01
14  1998-03-01
```

I tried below code:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y-%m')
```

But it did not replace the dates as shown below

`1997-02-02` to `1997-02-01`

`1997-04-02` to `1997-04-01`

`1997-12-31` to `1997-12-01`

`1998-02-28` to `1998-02-01`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']) + pd.offsets.DateOffset(day=1)

print (df)
         date
0  1997-01-01
1  1997-02-01
2  1997-03-01
3  1997-04-01
4  1997-05-01
5  1997-06-01
6  1997-07-01
7  1997-08-01
8  1997-09-01
9  1997-10-01
10 1997-11-01
11 1997-12-01
12 1998-01-01
13 1998-02-01
14 1998-03-01
```

Or:

```
d = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df['date'] = d  - pd.to_timedelta(d.dt.day - 1, 'd')

print (df)
         date
0  1997-01-01
1  1997-02-01
2  1997-03-01
3  1997-04-01
4  1997-05-01
5  1997-06-01
6  1997-07-01
7  1997-08-01
8  1997-09-01
9  1997-10-01
10 1997-11-01
11 1997-12-01
12 1998-01-01
13 1998-02-01
14 1998-03-01
```

Comment: can you please check this question you answered 2 years back. Will the same code work for panadas version 1.2.4? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60719348/compare-two-column-in-two-table-in-pandas-based-on-the-specific-condition